# ID of current text field on class-based autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery autocomplete:

```
 $( ".test"  ).autocomplete({
    search: function(event,ui) {
        $("#textfield" ).addClass('loadinggif');
    },
    response: function(event,ui) {
        $("#textfield").removeClass('loadinggif');
    },

      ....

   });
```

I have two text fields with the class "test" with different id's.

textfield obviously needs to be replace by the id of the text field that is currently being used on the form.

How could I determine which text field is in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` to reference the current element being opperated on.

```
$( ".test"  ).autocomplete({
    search: function(event,ui) {
        $(this).addClass('loadinggif');
    },
    response: function(event,ui) {
        $(this).removeClass('loadinggif');
    }

});
```

But in general you can use :focus `if($("#textfield").is(":focus"))`